# unserialize serialized array in php

Tags: php, serialization

I have an array in which all key values are in serialized manner here is the sample code

```
Array
(
    [Entry1] => Array
    (
        [emergency_contact] => s:205:"a:5:{s:22:"emergency_contact_name";s:0:"";s:23:"emergency_contact_email";s:0:"";s:23:"emergency_contact_phone";s:0:"";s:26:"emergency_contact_relation";s:0:"";s:30:"emergency_contact_rx_allergies";s:0:"";}";
        [email] => s:23:"h.v@gmail.com";
        [c_address] => s:14:"1067 Broad Way";
        [c_address2] => s:6:"Mangal";
        [c_postcode] => s:5:"12345";
        [c_city] => s:14:"Sans Frnasisco";
        [c_state] => s:7:"LOS";
        [c_country_of_residence] => s:3:"109";
    )
    [Entry2] => Array
    (
        [emergency_contact] => s:205:"a:5:{s:22:"emergency_contact_name";s:0:"";s:23:"emergency_contact_email";s:0:"";s:23:"emergency_contact_phone";s:0:"";s:26:"emergency_contact_relation";s:0:"";s:30:"emergency_contact_rx_allergies";s:0:"";}";
        [email] => s:23:"h.v@gmail.com";
        [c_address] => s:14:"1067 Broad Way";
        [c_address2] => s:6:"Mangal";
        [c_postcode] => s:5:"12345";
        [c_city] => s:14:"Sans Frnasisco";
        [c_state] => s:7:"LOS";
        [c_country_of_residence] => s:3:"109";
    )
)
```

is there any way i can view all the data change it and again serialize it again in the same manner?? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value) { $value = unserialize($value); });

// do something with the array

array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value) { $value = serialize($value); });
```

But really, having each individual value serialized is quite the madness. You should stop that if you can.